# Came across True false statements in function javascript, what is the point?

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

I was ripping apart some code from sharepoint and noticed that they have random true false statements in their functions. My first thought was that they would stop the next statement from being ran, but when I made a simple test, the console log showed it ran no matter what.

Could someone let me know what this is for, what the point is, and why you would do it.

here is an example I came across, and will post my test.

```
 function _SubmitFormPost(a, d, c) {
    if (typeof MSOWebPartPageFormName != "undefined") {

        var b = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName];

        if (null != b)
        {
            if (d != undefined && d == true || typeof b.onsubmit == "undefined" || b.onsubmit == null || b.onsubmit() != false) {
                //HERE IS A RANDOM EXAMPLE OF T/F 
                typeof window.WebForm_OnSubmit == "function" && window.WebForm_OnSubmit();
                if (ajaxNavigate.get_search().match(new RegExp("[?&]IsDlg=1")) != null)
                a += a.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?IsDlg=1" : "&IsDlg=1";
                if (FV4UI())
                try {
                    var e = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_ribbon().get_selectedTabId();
                    if (Boolean(e)) {
                        a = StURLSetVar2(a, "InitialTabId", escapeProperly(e));
                        a = StURLSetVar2(a, "VisibilityContext", "WSSTabPersistence")
                    }
                } catch (f) {}
                if (c != undefined && c == true) {
                    a = DemoteIntoFormBody(b, a, "owsfileref");
                    a = DemoteIntoFormBody(b, a, "NextUsing")
                }
                b.action = STSPageUrlValidation(a);
                b.method = "POST";
                if (isPortalTemplatePage(a))
                b.target = "_top";
                !bValidSearchTerm && _ClearSearchTerm("");
                b.submit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here was my test, the console window was hitting all the console.logs that I thought it wouldn't

```
function s(){
    console.log('in s')
    //is true
    if(1==1){
        //is true
        if(2==2){
            console.log(' if 2==2 and eval of t/f is ',typeof(1) =="function")
            //is false -- expexted to skip console.log
            typeof(1) =="function"
            console.log('2 is 2')
        }
        //is true
        2==3
        if(3==3){
            console.log('3==3')
        }
    }
}
s()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` doesn't just return a value. It also has a (flow control) effect: Its second operand is only evaluated if its first operand is true. That is, `A && B` doesn't run `B` if `A` is already `false`. (This is known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).)

In other words,

```
typeof window.WebForm_OnSubmit == "function" && window.WebForm_OnSubmit();
```

behaves like

```
if (typeof window.WebForm_OnSubmit == "function")
    window.WebForm_OnSubmit();
```

but is slightly shorter.

The point is not to return `true` or `false` (the result is ignored); the point is to only call `window.WebForm_OnSubmit` if it is defined as a function.

Similarly,

```
!bValidSearchTerm && _ClearSearchTerm("");
```

works like:

```
if (!bValidSearchTerm)
    _ClearSearchTerm("");
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I couldn't find it here or on google. I'm self taught, so I know a lot will be missed. Is there a name for this convention?

Comment: @user2620493 I don't know if it has a name, but I'm pretty sure it was first used in Lisp, then it spread to Perl, and from there to JavaScript. But from what I've seen so far, people don't normally write JavaScript code like this by hand; it's mostly generated by code minifiers and obfuscators.